# Change in my usual work / change from my usual work

Tags: prepositions, exam-questions

> This is a change **from/in** my usual work

Which is the correct preposition to use here ? I am not a native speaker so going by the literal meaning *in* sounds more appropriate but I guess  *from* is preferred. Can anyone explain  why is it so ?

Comment: This is a change from my usual work.

Answer (score 1):

As Lambie notes, this would most often be:
"This is a change from my usual work"

If "my usual work" is the set of work tasks that you regularly do, then the whole phrase means that "this (task)" is outside the set of work tasks you normally do (not "in").

If however your set of work tasks that you regularly do is being permanently changed to include "this (task)" then we might use either of:

- "This is a change in my usual work"
- "This is a change to my usual work"